# Working out consecutive days with longer resting periods

Tags: recovery

Supose you can only work out for five days, and you know you won't be able to do so in a couple of weeks after. Would it be better to work out five days on a row, since you'll have a longer than usual resting period, or would it be better to work out on alternative days as usual?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question. However, unless you are having some sort of surgery that will keep you from using your limbs. Pack a thera-band/stretchy-band. The biggest problem for your muscles will be the inactivity. So even if you can use a stretch-band for some kind of work out it will be beneficial. Plus, they don't take up a lot of space.

Comment: Accumulating tremendous volume before a long break isn't a terrible idea. Five days in a row is a little over the top though.

Comment: I would add that training 5 days in a row may not be bad, but, it really depends on the intensity.  you need to allow for sufficient recovery of not only your body, but, your central nervous system as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your body can only properly recover while resting so I would recommend sticking to alternative days.

That being said, if you have a two week break coming up then you have a great opportunity to change your routine up when you get back and see some quicker results.  Our bodies and minds are great at establishing patterns and if you stick to a workout routine for long enough, your body will become accustomed to it and not grow at the same rate as when the routine was started.  That's much of why people on a new diet see great results initially but then the rate at which they lose weight slows down.  Body builders sometimes break out of plateaus by changing their routine.

If you haven't stopped exercising, you can always finish with a bang by increasing the intensity a little bit (but remember to rest!).  Then when you get back into it, change things up.  Your body won't know what's going on and will have to compensate accordingly.